# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My doctrine repository code doesn't work, while I **am** able to access the database and read table data normally.

I get this stacktrace:

```
EntityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Person') in src\AppBundle\Controller\PersonViewController.php (line 18) 

  public function indexAction(Request $request) {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person');
         $persons = $repo->findAll();
         dump($persons);
```

The person entity model:

`Person.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Person
 * @Package AppBundle/Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="[Person]")
 */
class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
     */
    protected $type;
}
```

In case this is necessary as well, the repo code:

`PersonRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function create() {
        $entity = new Person();
        $entity->type('WM_B');
        $this->_em->persist($entity);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you inject own `DatabaseService` and open connection, instead of relying on Doctrine?

Comment: I'll take that out. I was just looking at if that part works.

Comment: The code you posted is completely useless. The error message posted in the title says that Doctrine is knocking on a closed door. The configuration is the problem.

Comment: The code was not the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Sql Server Network Configuration -> Protocols For  -> TCP/IP ->

I changed the following

```
IpAll
TCP Dynamic Ports 49226
TCP Port
```

To:

```
IpAll
TCP Dynamic Ports
TCP Port          1433
```

Not sure what TCP Dynamic Ports are and why they were configured.

Answer (score 3):

For **SQL Server 2019 Developer**

In default installation:

- TCP/IP is disabled
- Authentication is set to Windows Authentication mode only

**The Fix**

1. To enable TCP/IP:

   ```
   Start Menu
    -> Microsoft SQL Server 2019
    -> SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager 
    -> SQL Server Network Configuration 
    -> Protocols For MSSQLSERVER 
    -> TCP/IP
    -> Enable
   ```
2. To enable SQL Authentication mode:

   ```
    Start Menu
    -> Microsoft SQL Server Tools 
    -> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
    -> Right-Click the server node 
    -> Properties
    -> Security
    -> Under Authentication choose "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode"
   ```

3. The above changes needs restarting the "MSSQLSERVER" service.