# Protocol Error in TDS Stream on Laravel App on Azure

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel Application to Azure using the App Service.

Things are working pretty ok, I set the PHP version to 7.1, added the Composer extention, and added a web.config file in the public folder of my repo for supporting rewrites in IIS. After that I deployed through Git. I also set the correct environmental variables:

[image]

The only problem is, I can't connect to the Azure SQL Database. It gives me this strange Protocol Error, which I can't solve. Google only shows old answers... I hope someone can help me?

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL: select * from [settings]) (View: D:\home\site\wwwroot\........\resources\views\login.blade.php)`

Comment: Typically a network issue or ODBC drivers are corrupt or obsolete. Try reinstalling latest ODBC drivers on the client.

Comment: Alright, but what if the client is a cloud instance? Just using the App Service from Azure. How can I upgrade the driver?

Comment: *`Protocol error in TDS stream` typically indicates dropped packets during the communication. Try a simple query that will not return many results.* See @miken32's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223476/laravel-sql-server-sqlstatehy000-unixodbcmicrosoftodbc-driver-13-for-sq).

Comment: I'm trying a simple query... just a SELECT!

Comment: The ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server is the latest driver.  Can you share the DDL and sample data for that table?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turned out to be a corrupted instance of the Azure Web App. After deleting the App, and deploying a new clean version, it started working perfectly.