# Connecting php 7.2 to MS SQL using sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, php-7.2

I'm trying to get a connection to MS SQL up and running via PHP on my machine.  I'm running IIS, have PHP 7.2 installed and MS SQL Express 2017.  I have my basic web page running but when I click to open the PHP page, the connection does not work.

```php
session_start();

echo "Hello ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION["server"] = $_POST['server'];
    $_SESSION["database"]= $_POST['database'];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION["password"] = $_POST['password'];

    echo $_SESSION["database"];

    //CONNECTION
    $serverName = $_SESSION["server"];
    $connectionInfo["Database"] = $_SESSION["database"];
    $connectionInfo["UID"] = $_SESSION["username"];
    $connectionInfo["PWD"] = $_SESSION["password"];

    echo "midway";

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    echo "Bye";
}
```

When I run this I get "Hello dimensions midway" which suggests the page is working until it hits the connection line.
I am not sure what sqlsrv extension to use.
I have looked around and can see versions for 7 and 7.1 but not for 7.2.

I have added in `extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll` to the bottom of php.ini (and the file exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2\ext`).

Any pointers would be gratefully received. I've spent a couple of days on this and don't think I'm getting anywhere.
Thanks

Comment: Run a script that contains `phpinfo();` and it will dump a page that shows what's supported. Make sure the MSSQL driver is listed.

Comment: Yes. phpinfo() will show if you have MSSQL= SQLSERVER

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've run that and the driver isn't listed.  Does that mean it isn't supported or I simply haven't got a driver or its not available?

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. I should have said "currently loaded" instead of "supported." You'll need to install an extension that matches your PHP version.

Comment: Looking at the official binary distribution, I see it doesn't include a precompiled MSSQL driver -- I guess it's a licensing issue?

Comment: I can see a Microsoft version for v7.1 so I think I am going to have to downgrade to that version of php

Comment: @Daves - Looking at the [releases on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases) (specifically [5.1.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.1.1-preview)) there appears to be drivers for 7.2 - 'windows-7.2.zip' - though these are labelled as a pre-release

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same issue. Later I found that I was using older version of Microsoft SQL files for PHP.

For PHP 7.2 you have to use 7.2 version of MS PHP SQL

That version is not available through microsoft website. I found it here https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

Once I used those files everything works fine. I used 64 bit files.

Then you need to add these lines in the php.ini file

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
```

Answer (score 8):

What do you need to determine are

- Which version of PHP
- The runtime you are using is **Thread Safe** or **Non-Thread Safe**
- The runtime you are using is **64 bits** or **32 bits**

Then you must look at the requirement page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Check the version of PHP you are using, so prefer to your question, it's mean to `PHP 7.2` which **SQL Server extension version 5.3** is the best fit.

Then go to [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), select the link which specific with version you prefer. (in this question is **5.3**)

The file you downloaded will be a self-extractable **EXE** file, then extract to the place where you want.

you will see list of `dll` files like these...

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
...
php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
```

What is the meaning that is in the name of these files?

Like I said before, what you need to determine to select the proper extension file. The SQL Server extension need 2 files of the name start with `php_pdo_sqlsrv_xxx` and `php_sqlsrv_xxx`.

Next number mean to your `PHP` version, in this case `PHP 7.2`, so you need to choose file name has `_72_` in its.

Next number mean to your runtime **Thread Safe** or **Non-Thread Safe**, which specific in the file name `_ts_` (Thread Safe) or `_nts_` (Non-Thread Safe).

Next number mean to your runtime **32 bits** or **64 bits**, which specific in the file name `_x86` (32 bits) or `_x64` (64 bits)

So check your PHP environment by `phpinfo()`, or run the command `php --version` on your console, and then notice the message displayed, for my computer it look like these...

```
PHP 7.2.12 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2018 06:12:12) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

By look from those information, I got PHP `7.2`, `ZTS` mean to **Thread Safe** (**Non-Thread Safe** will be `NTS`), and the `x86` is **32 bits**.

So, what I must pick is the extension which are `php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll`

Final: copy them to your `/php/ext` folder and edit `php.ini` with those 2 files name.

```
// example with my case
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
```

Then save `php.ini` file and then restart your server.

Test your result by looking at `phpinfo.php`, which MUST has `pdo_sqlsrv` in the page. That's mean your environment can run PHP and connect to `SQL Server` now.

Comment: Hey @Natta, Can you send me the dll files you used? I have the exact same version and I am trying to download the drivers from this Git repo but it is not working
https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.3.0

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I figured out already. I had wrong version of odbc driver.

Comment: This is so incredibly badass. You saved me so much time! Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: Same version, did exactly as you told, `php -v` runs successfully, meaning it found the dlls, however in last step `phpinfo()` does not find anything related to `pdo_sqlsrv`

Comment: False alarm, turns out I was restarting Apache server, but I needed to restart node server >.<

Answer (score 2):

I solved it ~ 
PHP Version 7.2.4

pdo_sqlsrv : 5.3.0+11108

1.download the proper version sqlsrv and sqlsrv pdo

2.put it into XAMPP\PHP\ext folder

3.after that write the line into php.ini > module setting

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

4.let's make a test for MSSQL still there is a error msg for recommend you to download ODBC Driver for SQL

5.Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 then download the proper file

(mine is  Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server® X86)

6.fire the test.php again everything works!

Comment: 5) english version is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. All you have to do is use these extensions in `php.ini` file.

**php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll**

**php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll**

and restart your XAMPP.

P.S. "I am using PHP 7.2.5 "

Answer (score -1):

How to use `SQL Server DLL` files with `PHP 7.2` version on xampp

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

To download Windows DLLs for `PHP 7.1` or above from the `PECL` repository, please go to the `SQLSRV` or `PDO_SQLSRV PECL` page.

https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/5.6.1/windows

https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv/5.6.1/windows

NOTE: Do not forget to remove `php_` prefix when you add extension dll filename in `php.ini` file. eg.

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
extension=sqlsrv
```

** Do not change actual filename which you put in `/xampp/php/ext/` directory.

`7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86` worked for me for `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` extensions.

Restart xampp or apache then you can see enabled `pdo_sqlsrv` extension when you print `phpinfo()` in a test php file

[image]